# Django Models for 1:many relationship between Posts and Photos

Tags: python, django, models, relation

So i have two models; the first for posts and second photos. Each post can have many photos in it. & I am unsure how a one-to-many relationship can be constructed in django.

Heres my models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Photo(models.Model): 
    FILE_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('full', 'Full Width'), 
        ('half', 'Half Width')
    )       

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    photoType = models.CharField(max_length=16,choices = FILE_TYPE_CHOICES, default = 'full', blank = True)
    imageFile   = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploaded')

    containedPost = models.ForeignKey('Post', related_name='photoPosts')
```

How could I achieve a proper relation and how would I be able to access the post & each of the photos in the template?

Comment: This should work as is, although the `related_name` would be more accurate if it were `postPhotos` or just `photos` since this is the name of the relation as it appears on the `Post` object. For the rest of your question: *what have you tried?*

Comment: @Hamish with the corrected relation name i've tried something like: {{ post.postPhotos.0.title }} am I thinking this wrong?

Comment: @CallumBonnyman `{{ post.postPhotos.all.0.title }}` or `{% for photo in post.postPhotos.all %}{{ photo.title }}{% endfor %}`

Answer (score 0):

MODELS:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Photo(models.Model): 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    FILE_TYPES = (
        ('full', 'Full Width'), 
        ('half', 'Half Width')
    )       
    photo_type = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=FILE_TYPES, default='full', blank=True)
    imageFile   = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploaded')
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

TEMPLATE:

```
{% for photo in post.photo_set %}
    {{ photo }}
{% endfor %}
```